# Django Relations with Models

Tags: python, django, database, model, relationship

I try to figure a clever way out for my models.
I have two models where i want the Legend to have 4 different skills(Skill Model), but I cant seem to get the fitting model relation for it

```
class Skill(models.Model):   
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='skills/', blank=True, null=True)


class Legend(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='legends/%Y/', blank=True, null=True)
    skill_1 = models.(Skill, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    skill_2 = models.OneToOneField(Skill, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    skill_3 = models.OneToOneField(Skill, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    skill_4 = models.OneToOneField(Skill, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

The problem is I cant rly make a OneToOneField because it want´s a related_name for each, which would make No sense here, since they are all skills and I dont want to call for the owner (Legend) of the skill in 4 different ways

I also tried to make a legend field in the Skill model with a foreignkey on the Legend, but that didnt turned out how i wanted it to be.

thanks for the help ^.^

Comment: Why adding FK in Skill model to Legend is not what you want ? It is the most clean and intuitive way to go in my opinion

Comment: becuase i want each of them to be referenced in that style from Legend: skill1, skill1 etc.
Also i would not be able to limit the skillset on max 4 skills, also the order does matter in my example

Answer (score 0):

Moving my answer here, so I can format code

So... do it as I've said. Add FK in Skill pointing to Legend. Afterwards in your admin.py create admin class which inherits from `StackedInline` or `TabularInline`. Your file should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from apps.legends.models import Skill, Legend

class InlineAdminSkill(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Skill
    extra = 4
    max_num = 4

class LegendAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineAdminSkill]

admin.site.register(Legend, LegendAdmin)
```

This should resolve problem in admin - your skill will be visible in your admin legend view. Try it out.

In your views in the other hand you just have to add a logic which uses e.g. formsets and enables you adding max 4 skills.

Comment: as i`ve said before, thats exactly what i dont need/ want. The input will never be given in the admin view at all.
All I want is 4 pointers to different skills each in the model relation. If thats not possible this way, then thats fine